# Кодировка в Spring, jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, кодировка

Я захотел русские буквы в jsp страницах. И пошёл проставлять кодировки

Делай раз

```
<%@ page session="false" isELIgnored="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Делай два

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Делай три

```
@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;

}
```

**И нифига ((** А потом я добавил в web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

И оно заработало! Вопрос: Почему?
Ведь пока я гуглил про java-based configuration, я сто раз видел фразу "we don't need web.xml", а тут получается он играет главную роль. Можно ли это как-то перенести из web.xml в конфиги спринга?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну и по традиции наткнулся на ответ сразу же после того, как задал вопрос:
[за ответом сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706294/completely-replace-web-xml-with-java-config-spring-mvc-4-tomcat-7-8).
По ссылке сказано, что всё-таки конфигурация на основе java-кода не может заменить все такие штуки в web.xml. Поэтому придётся использовать и то, и то.

И теперь по поводу того, почему это вообще работает. А потому что после всех своих действий Spring нам выдаёт просто jsp страницу, поэтому такой url-pattern работает.